Vapor PSQLError: sqlState: 42883, file: parse_oper.c, hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types
I added a new function to my vapor server to query a postgres database for appointments using a userID.
func getAppointmentsByResidentID(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Appointment]> {
        let token = try req.auth.require(Token.self)
        guard let userIDString = req.parameters.get("userID"),
                      let userID = UUID(uuidString: userIDString) else {
                    throw Abort(.badRequest)
                }
        
        return Appointment.query(on: req.db)
            .filter(\.$userID == userID)
            .all()
    }

I get the following error:

[ WARNING ] PSQLError(code: server, serverInfo: [sqlState: 42883, file: parse_oper.c, hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts., line: 647, message: operator does not exist: text = uuid, position: 721, routine: op_error, localizedSeverity: ERROR, severity: ERROR], triggeredFromRequestInFile: PostgresKit/PostgresDatabase+SQL.swift, line: 60, query: PostgresQuery(sql: SELECT "appointments"."id" AS "appointments_id", "appointments"."userID" AS "appointments_userID", "appointments"."firstName" AS "appointments_firstName", "appointments"."lastName" AS "appointments_lastName", "appointments"."phoneNumber" AS "appointments_phoneNumber", "appointments"."date" AS "appointments_date", "appointments"."time" AS "appointments_time", "appointments"."house" AS "appointments_house", "appointments"."residentAddress" AS "appointments_residentAddress", "appointments"."addressOfAppt" AS "appointments_addressOfAppt", "appointments"."description" AS "appointments_description", "appointments"."hasRideScheduled" AS "appointments_hasRideScheduled" FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."userID" = $1, binds: [(****; UUID; format: binary)])) [request-id: 5FD0447F-581D-419C-B6E6-FE5AE011DFCD]

Any ideas on what might be causing this error and how to fix it?
Here's the appointments migration table, and I can see the problem now:
func prepare(on database: FluentKit.Database) async throws {
        //create residents table
        try await database.schema("appointments")
            .id()
            .field("userID", .string, .required)
            .field("firstName", .string, .required)
            .field("lastName", .string, .required)
            .field("phoneNumber", .string, .required)
            .field("date", .datetime, .required)
            .field("time", .string, .required)
            .field("house", .string, .required)
            .field("residentAddress", .string, .required)
            .field("addressOfAppt", .string, .required)
            .field("description", .string, .required)
            .field("hasRideScheduled", .bool, .required)
            .create()
    }

I am trying to use a UUID where it's looking for a string.

What does the migration look like for the appointment model? It looks like the column you're querying is not a UUID type

Thank you, that led me to the problem. The userID is not a UUID, it's a string.
